# Need to add total From Sheet 2 to cell in Sheet 1

Tags: excel

Heres what I got.  I got an NFL pick 'Em Spreadsheet for people im running.  I have an Overall Standings tab(Sheet 1) a Week 1 Tab(sheet 2) a Week 2 tab(Sheet 3), etc. for the year.  Once I get the total of that person in Sheet 2, 3, 4, etc. Im looking for a formula to add that total number from Sheet 2,3,4,etc. to that Person in Sheet 1.  Is it possible in Excel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can.  Add this to the cell you want the total to be in to add cell A1 from sheet 2 and 3 together:

```
='Week 1'!A1+'Week 2'!A1
```

All you do is put an equal sign (=) into the cell you want the result to be displayed and then click on the cell you want to add, type a plus sign (+) and then click on the next cell to add.  Doesn't matter what sheet it's on.